# In a bash script wait for a 3rd party ssh connection, do something, exit

Tags: bash

I am trying to deploy to a PaaS provider which of course doesn't offer direct SSH connections to my cluster.
For that we have a CLI tool provided, which is called like

```
clitool mycluster run bash
```

When calling it from my terminal it looks like opening a SSH connection:

```
Connecting...
Warning: Permanently added '[w.x.y.z]:1234' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

After that I usually do something like this

```
cd www
runsomecommand
exit
```

No I want to do the same thing in a bash script but even when I do something like

```
clitool mycluster run bash &
cd www & 
runsomecommand &
exit
```

it doesn't seem that the bash script is waiting for the connection to be created but is executing the 'cd www' command from its local directory which of course isn't what I require.

How to wait until connection is opened and my bash script is executing commands in the opened connection? Any way?

Comment: I think the `expect` language is what you are looking for, it waits for the expected output that a connection is made then executes commands and exits

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but try this:

```
clitool mycluster run bash " cd www ; ls -la "
```